# how to redirect users to full sign-up page from join me on landing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, to be clear I have a Join Now section on the landing page with 4 out of 10 form fields I'd like users to fill out these 4 fields and then be re-directed to the full sign-up page to complete the profile. One solution was add validations on the other fields and when they aren't met on the Join Us form the user is redirected to the full sign-up page.

Are there any other better alternative ways to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: You could use a the [workflow gem](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) to define a state for your user and based on it redirect to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really broad and there are many possible solutions, for which everyone may have its own preferences.

To be honest, I don't really understand why you would require someone to fill in 4 fields and after that require them to fill in another 6 fields once those fields are validated. Why not let him or her fill in all 10 fields to begin with.

Or you could just let someone fill in 4 fields (for example username, e-mail, password, password_confirmation) and store the results of these (validated) fields in your users table. Once this first step is finished, someone can log in. For additional options you can require someone to complete his profile. The first 4 fields are disabled (you could use the data stored in the table as placeholder) and once the user fills the other required fields with valid data the user record will be updated with additional data.

Even better would be using a wizard, where you use multiple steps. Following this railscast would be a nice start:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast